# Gallery returns different URI of media files for Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT for different Android Versions

Tags: android, android-intent

Here is a code to call intent to open gallery for images.

```
public void getImage() {
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setType("image/*");
        i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        //Intent customChooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(i, "Pick an image");
        startActivityForResult(i, 10);
 }
```

Response receive on Activity result

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == 10) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                String selectedImagePath = getRealPathFromURI(selectedImageUri);
              }               
}
```

Code to getRealPathfromURI()

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        Cursor cursor = getActivity().managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
```

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32881074/filenotfoundexception-while-picking-images-from-gallery/32881215#32881215

Comment: Delete `getRealPathFromURI()`, as it will not work reliably. [A `Uri` is not a file](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/04/uri-not-necessarily-file.html). It may not represent anything you can access on the filesystem. Use methods on a `ContentResolver`, such as `openInputStream()`, to use the `Uri`.

Comment: @Stella look at my answer, its much more easier than that solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got simple answer, just encrypt path on basis of android SDK version.

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri uri) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
        String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        Cursor cursor = getActivity().managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    } else {
        String selectedImagePath = null;
        String wholeID = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
       // Split at colon, use second item in the array
        String id = wholeID.split(":")[1];
        String[] column = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        // where id is equal to
        String sel = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=?";
        Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, column, sel, new String[]{id}, null);
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(column[0]);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            selectedImagePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        }
        cursor.close();
        return selectedImagePath;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A very simple code for this (Tested)

Image:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 19) {
                        Intent i = new Intent();
                        i.setType("image/*");
                        i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                        startActivityForResult(i, 10);
                    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 19) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, 10);
                    }
```

Video:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 19) {
                        Intent i = new Intent();
                        i.setType("video/*");
                        i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                        startActivityForResult(i, 20);
                    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 19) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, 20);
                    }
```

.

```
     @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            if (requestCode == 10) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                String selectedImagePath = getRealPathFromURI(selectedImageUri);
            } else if (requestCode == 20) {
                Uri selectedVideoUri = data.getData();
                String selectedVideoPath = getRealPathFromURI(selectedVideoUri);
            }

     public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri uri) {
            if (uri == null) {
                return null;
            }
            String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
            if (cursor != null) {
                int column_index = cursor
                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            }
            return uri.getPath();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code to call intent to open gallery for images.

```
Intent i = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

            startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
```

Response receive on Activity result

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK
            && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        bmImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);

        // setting bitmap to imageview
        // coImage.setImageBitmap(bmImage);

        strEncodeImg = encodeTobase64(bmImage);

        Log.e("Image set successfully...!", "yes......................");
        coImage.setImageBitmap(decodeBase64(strEncodeImg));
    }

}
```

You can save this image in string format in database or you can do anything with this string no need to store images in folders its just bitmap code.
So easy.